# Is it better to give Ma'aser Kesofim to Talmidei chochomim who are not poor or to poor Yidden who are not Talmidei chochomim?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

What is the ideal way to give Ma'aser Kesofim? Is it better to give Ma'aser Kesofim to Talmidei chochomim who are not poor or to poor Yidden who are not Talmidei chochomim?

Comment: Is there a mitsva to give it to someone who is not poor at all?

Comment: Rav Hutner says that *talmidei chachamim* are more *ne'ehav* (lovable) and therefore take precedence in *mitzvos* that are based on the *mitzva* of *ve'ahavta le'reachah komochah*.

Comment: If they're not poor then why do they need the money?

Comment: "not poor at all" "If they're not poor" These sound like reasonable questions, but it's a pretty common circumstance that there are kollel people who have trouble making ends meet. The tzedakah enables them to continue their studies. Or rebbis in yeshivos that don't pay much or on time. They may not be _as_ poor as the ones they're being compared to.